# How to correct typos in tags

Tags: support, tagging

Recently, the [conersionrules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conersionrules) tag was created. Setting the discussion of its usefulness aside, how can we correct its spelling (should be [conversionrules](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversionrules))?

On the tag's [synonym suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/conersionrules/synonyms) page, it says:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms.

The problem is that the tag only has the score of 1, and the typo will cause it to be noticed even less, further diminishing the chance of it being corrected.

Is there another way to correct mistyped, low-score tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At present there are no questions bearing that tag; presumably someone retagged the sole question which was surely the simplest solution in this case.  If there were many questions with a misspelled tag a moderator could perform a tag merge or the community could create a synonym.

If you find a misspelled tag please flag one of the posts for moderator attention.

Comment: How long does it take for unused tags to get deleted? Or does it have to be done manually?

Comment: @Oleksandr [rm -rf explained here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1108/is-it-possible-to-remove-tags-created-by-mistake#comment4807_1109)

Comment: Thanks. I had obviously read that but I didn't remember having done so. 24 hours (maximum) is quicker than I would have imagined, but seems like a sensible schedule.